# Borrar articulo en un arraylist iterando en Java

Tags: java

Estoy con un ejercicio de clase, el cual indica que tienes que pedir al usario el codigo de ese articulo y si existe, borrar ese articulo del arrayList. Mi duda es, He intentado hacer esto, pero no habría que especificar en el segundo while lo que debería borrar? He intentado poner código en remove pero me da fallo. Haber si me podeis echar una mano. Gracias de antemano.

Os pongo el enunciado.

**borrarArticulo**: pide código del articulo a borrar. Recorre la colección con la herramienta iterador en busca del contacto y lo elimina, informando de la no existencia del mismo dado el caso.

En esta clase se podrán incluir aquellos métodos que se consideren oportunos y estén relacionados con la gestión de objetos de la colección o de la colección en sí.

Estos son el arraylist que he hecho y el iterador:

```
private ArrayList<Articulo> coleccion = new ArrayList();
Iterator<Articulo> iter= coleccion.iterator();
```

Clase Articulo:

```
public class Articulo {
    //Creamos los atributos
    private String codigo;
    private String descripcion;
    private String existencias;
```

Metodo borrarArticulo:

```
public String borrarArticulo(){
    String codigo= null;
    boolean errorProducto = false;

    try{
        do{
            System.out.println("Por favor introduzca el codigo del articulo");
            codigo = teclado.nextLine();
            errorProducto = ValidarCodigo(codigo);
        }while(errorProducto);
        while(iter.hasNext()){
            if(coleccion.contains(iter.next())){
            iter.remove();
            }
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.err.println("Error");
    }
    return codigo;
    }
```

Comment: Dices que te da error al poner remove - qué error es?

Comment: Me da error al poner codigo en el remove, aun que no se si lo tengo que poner ahí, la cosa es que borre el articulo con el codigo que meto.

Answer (score 1):

puedes remover elementos de una collection directamente sin iterar. Por ejemplo:

1. Tienes tu coleccion `ArrayList<Articulo> coleccion = new ArrayList();`
2. El elemento introducido por teclado `String codigo = teclado.nextLine();`
3. Para remover el elemento introducido puedes utiliar la funcion (**removeIf**) del arrayList:
   `coleccion.removeIf((articulo) -> articulo.getCodigo().equals(codigo));`

Saludos !

Comment: La cosa es que me exige el ejercicio iterar...

Answer (score 0):

A mi no me da ningún error pero tampoco hace lo que se pretende. Lo que hace es eliminar todos los objetos de la lista - el if es siempre **true**.

Crea unos métodos get y set para los atributos de la clase Articulo y modifica el if en el segundo bucle así:

```
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    if (iter.next().getCodigo().equals(codigo)) {
        iter.remove();
    }
}
```

**EDITADO**

Compilado con JDK7.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class Articulo {

    // Creamos los atributos
    private String              codigo;
    private String              descripcion;
    private String              existencias;

    public Articulo() {

    }
    public Articulo(String c, String d, String e) {
        this.setCodigo(c);
        this.descripcion = d;
        this.existencias = e;
    }

    private ArrayList<Articulo> coleccion   = new ArrayList();

    public String borrarArticulo() {
        String codigo = "2";
        boolean errorProducto = false;

        coleccion.add(new Articulo("1", "1", "11"));
        coleccion.add(new Articulo("2", "b", "22"));
        coleccion.add(new Articulo("3", "c", "33"));

        System.out.println(coleccion);

        Iterator<Articulo> iter= coleccion.iterator();

        try {
//          do {
//              System.out.println("Por favor introduzca el codigo del articulo");
//              codigo = teclado.nextLine();
//              errorProducto = ValidarCodigo(codigo);
//          } while (errorProducto);
            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                if (iter.next().getCodigo().equals(codigo)) {
                    iter.remove();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error");
        }

        System.out.println(coleccion);
        return codigo;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new Articulo().borrarArticulo();
    }
    public String getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }
    public void setCodigo(String codigo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }

}
```

Comment: Me da error si lo hago como tu

Comment: Puedes poner el log del error, por favor

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

Comment: Como veo que no nos entendemos en tema de poner TODO el log del error, edito mi post y te pongo mi código que funciona y no lanza ningún error

Comment: Todo el log es esto:
xception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
 at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:901)
 at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:851)
 at incera1almacen.Almacen.borrarArticulo(Almacen.java:206)
 at incera1almacen.Principalincera1.main(Principalincera1.java:68)
C:\Users\ivan_\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 12 seconds)